# Cake php Search with multiple like condition

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_details
WHERE material_id LIKE  '%4'
OR material_id LIKE  '%5'
ORDER BY  `product_details`.`material_id` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

My Condition is like

```
$conditions[] = array(
    'OR' => array(
        'LOWER(`Product`.`product_name`) LIKE' => '%'.$search_query.'%',
        'LOWER(`ProductDetail`.`designer_id`) LIKE' => '%'.$get_designer_id.'%',
        'LOWER(`Product`.`category_id`) LIKE' => '%'.$get_category_id.'%',
        'LOWER(`ProductDetail`.`color_id`) LIKE' => $color_id,
        'LOWER(`ProductDetail`.`material_id`) LIKE' => '%'.$meterial_id.'%',
        'LOWER(`ProductDetail`.`product_code`) LIKE' => '%'.$search_query.'%',
        //'LOWER(`ProductDetail`.`gbp_price`) LIKE' => '%'.$search_query.'%',
       // 'LOWER(`ProductDetail`.`euro_price`) LIKE' => '%'.$search_query.'%',
        'LOWER(`ProductDetail`.`description`) LIKE' => '%'.$search_query.'%',   
    ),             
);
```

How To write this query in cake php

Comment: 'LOWER(`ProductDetail`.`material_id`) LIKE' => '%'.$meterial_id.'%',

Comment: Update your question, don't comment it... And I asked for PHP code, not SQL

Comment: I am not getting how to use OR ...

Comment: Still not editing the question, but using comments...

Comment: Use https://github.com/CakeDC/search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's beyond me why you would `LOWER()` id fields and why that isn't in your raw query.
But the raw query roughly translates to this CakePHP find :

```
$this->ProductDetail->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'material_id LIKE' => '%4',
            'material_id LIKE' => '%5',
        )
    ),
    'order' => array('material_id' => 'ASC'),
    'limit' => '0, 30'
));
```